# Laravel view not displaying

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hi after I click on a page:

```
<a href="{{ url('pages') }}">Websites</a>
```

i get an error saying:

> View [layoults.pages] not found.

Route:

```
Route::get('pages', 'BuilderController@websites');
```

ControlleR:

```
function websites()
    {
        $websites = Website::all();
        return view('layoults/pages', ['websites' => $websites]);
        $webid= $websites->id;
    }
```

pages.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('title', 'Website Builder') @section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<div class=flex-container>
    <div class="flex-item templates">

        @foreach ($websites as $website)
        <a class="content-link" href="{{ asset($website->name )}}">
        </a> @endforeach

    </div>
</div>        
        </body>
        <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset ('//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js') !!}">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-formhelpers.js') !!}">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/template.js') !!}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js') !!}">
        </script>

        </html>
        @endsection @show
```

So could someone please tell me what is going on? as far as I can see, everything seems correct.

Comment: I hope you are not having a typo issue with `layouts` and `layoults`?

Comment: Indeed its probably a typo

Comment: weird because other blades work fine

Comment: @Przemek Maybe you spelled the other ones right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typo in your code try following lines in your controller

function websites()
{
   $websites = Website::all();
   return view('layouts/pages', ['websites' => $websites]);
}
```